# will maven-shade-plugin exclude rename classes's location in "import"?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- put your configurations here -->
                    <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
                    <shadeSourcesContent>true</shadeSourcesContent>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core</include>
                            <include>org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.apache</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shade.org.apache</shadedPattern>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>javax.security</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shade.javax.security</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>javax.servlet</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shade.javax.servlet</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>javax.annotation</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shade.javax.annotation</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The above is my configuration for maven-shade-plugin.

in `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer`, it imports `org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase`. After mavan-shade-plugin shades after packaging and installing, the class, StandardServer, is shaded and relocated to `shade.org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer`, but I hope it still import `org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase` rather than `shade....LifecycleMBeanBase`, but actually it becomes `shade.org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase`. The worse thing is that in fact `LifecycleMBeanBase` isn't shaded, in other words, it still locate in `org.apache.catalina.util` so `StandardServer` lose `LifecycleMBeanBase`.

Thanks for any help.